# Add query parameter in WebClient request

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am using Spring WebFlux where I am taking request and using same request to call another service. But I am not sure how to add query parameters. This is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value= ["/ptta-service/**"])
suspend fun executeService(request: ServerHttpRequest): ServerHttpResponse {

    val requestedPath = if (request.path.toString().length > 13) "" else request.path.toString().substring(13)

    return WebClient.create(this.dataServiceUrl)
                    .method(request.method ?: HttpMethod.GET)
                    .uri(requestedPath)
                    .header("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*")
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request.body))
                    .retrieve()
                    .awaitBody()
                    // But how about query parameters??? How to add those
}
```

Though code is in Kotlin, Java will help as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add the query parameters using lambda expression in [uri](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M4_to_5.0.0.M5/Spring%20Framework%205.0.0.M5/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html#create-java.lang.String-), for more information see [WebClient.UriSpec](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M4_to_5.0.0.M5/Spring%20Framework%205.0.0.M5/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.UriSpec.html)

```
 return WebClient.create(this.dataServiceUrl)
                .method(request.method ?: HttpMethod.GET)
                .uri(builder -> builder.path(requestedPath).queryParam("q", "12").build())
                .header("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request.body))
                .retrieve()
                .awaitBody()
```

Comment: Thank you solution was `.uri { builder -> builder.path(requestedPath).queryParams(request.queryParams).build() }` in Kotlin. But you suggestion was correct.

Comment: How to use Webclient this if GET method has parameter with @Modalattribute ?